What conditions on the rate matrix $Q$ ensure unique convergence in continuous-time Markov chains?
In the study of discrete-time Markov chains, the conditions under which all initial distributions converge to a unique stationary distribution are well-understood. Specifically, if the transition matrix $\mathbf{P}$ has all strictly positive entries, this is a sufficient condition. The discrete-time probability transition equation is given by:
$$ \pi(n+1) = \pi(n)\mathbf{P}, $$
where $\pi(n)$ represents the state distribution at time $n$ and $\mathbf{P}$ is the transition matrix. This condition directly relates to the matrix elements and is easy to verify.
For continuous-time Markov chains with finite states, the probabilities follow the Kolmogorov forward equation:
$$ \frac{d\pi(t)}{dt} = \pi(t)\mathbf{Q},$$
where $\pi(t)$ is the probability distribution vector at time $t$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ is the transition rate matrix. I am also interested in understanding the conditions under which this equation converges to a unique stationary distribution.
There seem to be some abstract sufficient and necessary conditions, such as connectivity and irreducibility (as I gathered from ChatGPT, and I'm open to correction if my understanding is wrong). However, these criteria seem somewhat challenging to verify directly.
Question:
I would like to know if there exist any criteria directly related to the elements of the transition rate matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ that can determine whether the continuous-time finite-state Markov chain will converge to a unique stationary distribution. This criterion can be sufficient but not necessary, similar to the discrete-time case where all elements of the transition matrix being strictly positive is a sufficient condition.
I believe this problem won't be very difficult because it is essentially just about linear ODEs. Additionally, I am looking for references or textbooks that discuss this specific question.
There is a related question (Convergence to unique stationary distribution for SDEs and Markov processes) I previously asked on MO.
This question was previously posted on MSE (link: What conditions on the rate matrix Q
ensure unique convergence in continuous-time Markov chains?).

I think it's a better question for MSE than MO. There are undergraduate books that discuss this, e.g. Durrett's Essentials of Stochastic Processes. Irreducibility is an important property to understand and worth taking the time to do so. When you do, you will see that "all entries positive" is certainly sufficient.

@NateEldredge: At first glance I was inclined to agree that this is better suited for MSE. Yet, the last link in the question shows that the OP has already asked the same question on MSE three and a half days ago without any response so far.

For continuous time Markov Chains on finite state spaces, see Chapter 20 of "Markov Chains and Mixing Times, second edition". Are Theorems 20.1 and 20.3 answering your question?

@jlewk Seems a good suggestion, would you like to write an answer based on it? Comments shouldn't be used to answer questions.

For continuous time Markov Chains on finite state spaces, see Chapter 20 of "Markov Chains and Mixing Times, second edition", for instance in Theorems 20.1 and 20.3.
A short summary is that with $q(x,y)$ the rate for jumping from $x$ to $y$, define
$q(x,x) = - q(x)$ where $q(x) =\sum_{y\ne x} q(x,y)$. By properties of exponential races, the next distinct state of the continuous chain, after $x$, is chosen according to the discrete distribution $q(x,y)/q(x)$. Such matrix $q$ verifies that the heat kernel matrix $H_t(x,y)= \mathbf P_x[X_t=y]$ satisfies
$$
(d/dt) H_t = H_t Q.
$$
To this continuous-time chain with rate $q$ is associated a discrete chain with transition matrix $P(x,y)= q(x,y)/r$ for $x\ne y$ and $P(x,x)=1-q(x)/r$
and $r = \max_x q(x)$ (larger $r$ would work, too, in order to define an associated discrete time Markov chain). If $P$ is irreducible then
$$
\max_x \lim_{t\to\infty}  \| H_t(x,\cdot) - \pi\|_{TV} = 0.
$$
That $P^k$ has positive off-diagonal entries for some $k$ is sufficient for irreducibility.
Edit: Quoting Jochen in the comments, "Uniqueness of the stationary distribution is equivalent to the property that the directed graph associated with $Q$ has at least one vertex that can be reached from every other vertex by a path." This is enough to ensure convergence as above. In this case, there is only one essential communicating class in the state space, the chain eventually reaches this class with probability one, and the transition matrix $P$ restricted to this class is irreducible.
Compared with the discrete case, there is no need for aperiodicity thanks to continuous time jumps.

Upvoted. The sentence "Irreducibility cannot be relaxed" is not completely accurate, though. Uniqueness of the stationary distribution is equivalent to the property that the directed graph associated with $Q$ has at least one vertex that can be reached from every other vertex by a path. This is a weaker property than irreducibilty of the chain.
